# Is there a way to retrieve a datetime field to a specific timezone by default in Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, django-orm

I've an attribute in a django model like :

`created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

and in my `settings.py` I've configurations like :

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dhaka'
USE_TZ = True
```

`create_at` field is getting saved in UTC when I create an object. I want to retrieve this field in a specific timezone like `Asia/Dhaka`.

Is there a way to retrieve queryset where `created_at` field will be in my desired timezone?

Thank you

Comment: you can get value of the `created_at` field and then convert it to wanted timezone like so https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/converting-time-zones-datetime-objects-python/#convert-timezones

Answer (score 1):

i think you need the dajngo util [localtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime)

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime
localtime(create_at)
```